# Aiogram сохранять ответы пока не нажата кнопка

Tags: python, aiogram

Пытаюсь реализовать следующий функционал тг бота на aiogram
По нажатию inline кнопки "Заявка", бот начинает принимать ответы от пользователя, пока не будет нажата markup кнопка "Отправить заявку". И тогда все отправленные сообщения между нажатиями этих кнопок будут сохраняться, сейчас не принципиально куда (файл, бд)

Идей немного( только машина состояний, которая каким то образом зациклена на обновлении одного состояния, пока не будет принят

Или как то выстроить handler'ы чтобы отлавливать текстовые сообщения между нажатиями кнопок.

Буду рад любой подсказке/идеи куда смотреть/копать

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю можно просто в хендлере с текстом сделать проверку условную:

```
if user_id in active_users:  # (active_users - список юзеров которые нажали на кнопку)
    users[user_id].append(message.text)  # (users - условный словарь пользователей, из которого в будущем будут доставаться сообщения)
```

все это естественно нужно хранить где-то (например в json)

Дальше в хендлере с кнопкой примерно такой код:

```
with open(f'{user_id}.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(users[user_id]))
```

Надеюсь помог)

Answer (score 0):

Так конечные автоматы для этого и используются
[FSM в документации](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/finite_state_machine/index.html)

Создаешь специальный класс со стейтами, в них записываешь выбор пользователя. Затем получаешь значения из класса и записываешь их БД или в файл или еще куда

Пример класса:

```
class Form(StatesGroup):
    name = State()
    like_bots = State()
    language = State()
```

Пример хендлера, где устанавливается первый стейт:

```
@form_router.message(CommandStart())
async def command_start(message: Message, state: FSMContext) -> None:
    await state.set_state(Form.name)  #<--- вот он
    await message.answer(
        "Hi there! What's your name?",
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),
    )
```

Comment: А если я заранее не знаю количество стейтов? Вернее по сути он один, который должен дозаписываться после нового ответа пользователя и сделать финиш, когда получит сообщение от кнопки.

Comment: @petrgrishin И в чем проблема? Держите пользователя в этом одном стейте и записывайте все сообщения. Только не совсем понимаю, как это не знать количество стейтов? В общем случае стейт - это ждем ответа на какой-то вопрос. Я не могу представить ситуацию, когда неизвестно количество этих вопросов